# Where to ask question about software for recording the screen on Windows 10

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have no idea where to post such questions. Specifically on which site.

**My question:**

I want to record my screen including the sound from the laptop and the input from my microphone.
What is good software for that on Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

The only site that the question is on-topic on is the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Additionally, check out the [screen-recording](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-recording) tag on there. It looks like there are questions similar to yours. ([@Ollie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356798/where-to-ask-question-about-software-for-recording-screen-on-windows-10/356799?noredirect=1#comment1192180_356799))

You should not post this question on Super User as it's [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) per site guidelines.

Comment: [Oops](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-recording).